# Reactjs: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs

I m getting following issue when i try getting threads on page
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') occurring in this piece of code :

```
                 <ul className="thread-list">
                    <label>Messages</label>
                    {
                    this.props.threads.map((thread, threadIndex) => {
                        return(
                            <li>
                        <Link to={`/${thread.id}`}>
                            <i className="zmdi zmdi-account-circle" />
                            <h5>{thread.id}</h5>
                            <p>This is the last message</p>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                        );
                    })}
                    
                </ul>
```

actions:-

```
 case 'INITIAL_THREADS':
          dispatch({
              type: 'INITIAL_THREADS',
              payload: data.data,
                    });
```

reducer:-

```
case "INITIAL_THREADS":
        return {
           ...state,
           threads: action.payload
```

server :-

```
ws.on('connection', (ws) => {
    function getInitialThreads(userId){
        models.Thread.find({ where: {}}, (err, threads) => {
            if(!err && threads){
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'INITIAL_THREADS',
                    data: threads,
                }));
            }
        });

    }
            }
```

Comment: one of the threads is possibly undefined. you could perform a filter to remove the undefined element or you could check inside the map if thread is not undefined and then render content, thread && <li>....</li>

Comment: If you are fetching it from the server then of course you will face this problem. You need to wait for the response before the render. Can you please share the exact error message?

Comment: Please format your code better next time as well.

Comment: @ShamimFahad thank you for attention but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: @Ammar exact error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
Sidebar.render
C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Reactjs/chat/src/components/partials/Sidebar.js:59
  56 |  </ul>
  57 | :
  58 | <ul className="thread-list">
> 59 |     <label>Messages</label>
     | ^  60 |     { 
  61 |     this.props.threads.map((thread, threadIndex) => {
  62 |        return(

Comment: @DanZuzevich   thank you for your suggestion i will keep this in mind

Comment: "this.props.threads.map" if this line is in **Sidebar.js** file, then please try to write this as (this.props?.threads || []).map